# Weird behaviour encountered using java.sql.TimeStamp and a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

The weird behavior is that a java.sql.Timestamp that I create using the System.currentTimeMillis() method, is stored in my MySQL database as 1970-01-01 01:00:00.

The two timestamps I am creating are to mark the beginning and end of a monitoring task I am trying to perform, what follows are excepts from the code where the behavior occurs

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(numberOfTimeStepsPassed < numTimeStep) {
/*
* Code in here 
*/
}
final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
return mysqlConnection.insertDataInformation(matrixOfRawData, name,Long.toString(startTime), 
                                                 Long.toString(endTime), Integer.toString(numTimeStep),
                                                 Integer.toString(matrixOfRawData[0].length), owner,
                                                 type);
```

And here is the code used for inserting the time stamps and other data into the MySQL database

```
public String insertDataInformation(final  double [][] matrix,
                                    final String ... params) {
    getConnection(lookUpName);
    String id = "";
    PreparedStatement dataInformationInsert = null;
    try {
        dataInformationInsert =
                databaseConnection.prepareStatement(DATA_INFORMATION_PREPARED_STATEMENT);
        id = DatabaseUtils.createUniqueId();
        int stepsMonitored = Integer.parseInt(params[STEPS_MONITORED]);
        int numberOfMarkets = Integer.parseInt(params[NUMBER_OF_MARKETS]);
        dataInformationInsert.setNString(ID_INDEX, id);
        dataInformationInsert.setNString(NAME_INDEX, params[0]);
        dataInformationInsert.setTimestamp(START_INDEX, new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(params[START_INDEX])));
        dataInformationInsert.setTimestamp(END_INDEX, new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(params[END_INDEX])));
        dataInformationInsert.setInt(STEPS_INDEX, stepsMonitored);
        dataInformationInsert.setInt(MARKETS_INDEX, numberOfMarkets);
        dataInformationInsert.setNString(OWNER_INDEX, params[OWNER]);
        dataInformationInsert.setNString(TYPE_INDEX, params[TYPE]);
        dataInformationInsert.executeUpdate();
        insertRawMatrix(matrix, id, Integer.toString(stepsMonitored), Integer.toString(numberOfMarkets));
    } catch (SQLException sqple) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        sqple.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(sqple.getSQLState());
    } finally {
        close(dataInformationInsert);
        dataInformationInsert = null;
        close(databaseConnection);
    }
    return id;
}
```

The important lines of code are :

```
dataInformationInsert.setTimestamp(START_INDEX, new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(params[START_INDEX])));
dataInformationInsert.setTimestamp(END_INDEX, new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(params[END_INDEX])));
```

The JavaDocs on the TimeStamp ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html ) says that it takes in time in milliseconds since 1st January 1970 and a simple print test confirms this.

What I am looking for is:

- A reason for this behavior when trying to store timestamps in a MySQL database through `java.sql.Timestamp`?
- Any solutions to this behavior?
- Any possible alternatives?
- Any possible improvements?

EDIT: 
Been asked to include what START_INDEX and END_INDEX are:

```
 private static final int END_INDEX = 4;
 private static final int START_INDEX = 3;
```

Apologises for not putting them in the original post.

Comment: Why are you converting the value to a string and back? Why not just take each parameter in a strongly-typed way?

Comment: When I was originally writing the code I was unsure how many parameters the method would need, so I decided to make use of the String ... args to save myself some time at the time :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you change that right away. You can always use a separate "builder" for the parameters, so that you don't rely on ordering. Currently we can't see what START_INDEX etc are, so the problem *could* be there... we can't tell.

Comment: Just added what START_INDEX and END_INDEX are defined as in an edit to my original post.

Comment: Also just after re reading what you have stated there, I would like to clarify that I am getting no SQL exception being thrown. The data does get inserted into the database, just in the case of the time stamps they appear as I stated above, 1970-01-01 01:01:00

Comment: What's the value of `numTimeStep` out of interest? See my answer for why it could be relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, look at your call:

```
insertDataInformation(matrixOfRawData, name, Long.toString(startTime), 
                      Long.toString(endTime), Integer.toString(numTimeStep),
                      Integer.toString(matrixOfRawData[0].length), owner,
                      type);
```

So `params` will have values:

```
0: name
1: start time
2: end time
3: numTimeStep
4: matrixOfRowData[0].length
5: owner
6: type
```

Then you're doing:

```
dataInformationInsert.setTimestamp(START_INDEX,
    new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(params[START_INDEX])));
```

... where START_INDEX is 3.

So you're using the value corresponding to `numTimeStep` as the value for the timestamp... I suspect you don't want to do that.

I would *strongly* advise you to create a simple object type (possibly a nested type in the same class) to let you pass these parameters in a strongly typed, *simple to get right* fashion. The string conversion and the access by index are both unwarranted, and can easily give rise to errors.

Comment: That would be correct but those params values do not match up directly with the above statements. For a number of reasons the name index isn't the first parameter set, the id is (created inside the method) and the JDBC seems to start indexing parameters at 1 not at 0. Which is strange I know. I am sure of these because a mysql exception would be thrown if the ordering of my parameters was wrong. If there is a plus side you have convinced me to change the parameters to strongly typed. I forgot my code has to be readable to others not just me!

Comment: @OpelMac: I have no idea what you mean, but the code you've *posted* has the problem I've described. If your actual code is significantly different, then I'm not sure how I'm meant to be able to help you...

Comment: I accidently hit enter earlier on before finishing my comment. I apologise for that :)

Comment: @OpelMac: I'm not talking about the JDBC indexing - I'm talking about the *array* indexing. You are using  `new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(params[START_INDEX])));` which is fetching `params[3]`. Unless that *actually* corresponds to your start timestamp, that's a very real problem. (Getting the right JDBC parameter index is *another* challenge, but we can't see your SQL so we can't tell if that bit is right.)

Comment: Sorry about that. You are 200% right! If I knew who you were I would buy you a drink for this! Thanks a million man. You deserve all those medals!